# After updating, icons in wingpanel are not shown on elementary OS

Tags: ubuntu, user-interface, ubuntu-12.04, elementary-os

Note that eOS Luna = Ubuntu 12.04.

Before the update I saw dropbox and redshift icons. After the update and reboot when I start these apps, icons are not shown (but apps are working).

Can I fix that? How?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solve that.

Just install `python-appindicator`.